# error manipulating cursor result from mongodb while getting resuts to android client

Tags: php, android, mongodb, cursor

I'm connecting to local web server from android client and getting results back from mongodb database.

```
<?php
        $Earth_radius = 6378.137; //KM 
                $required_distance = 20; //KM




                if(! isset($_POST['long']) || ! isset($_POST['lat']) )
                {
                    echo 'NOT SET'; //exit();

                }


                $long = $_POST['lat'];
               $lat = $_POST['long'];

                // open connection to MongoDB server
                $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

                // access database
                $db = $conn->matabatdb;

                // access collection
                $collection = $db->matabat;

                $center=array($long,$lat);
                $radius=$required_distance/$Earth_radius; //convert to radians

                echo 'Im Ok here ';

               $result = $collection->find(array("loc"=>array('$within'=>array('$centerSphere'=>array($center,$radius)))));
    echo ' I can reach here';

var_dump($result->getNext());



         echo 'I do not reach this line';



?>
```

Any manipulation to $result doesn't provide any feedback response to android client

```
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {


                String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(".*?<body.*?>(.*?)</body>.*?",Pattern.DOTALL);

                Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(responseText);
                if(matcher.find()) {
                    String userID = matcher.group(1).trim();


                }
                else
                    Log.i(TAG," POST RESPONSE "+ responseText);



            }
            else
                Log.i(TAG," POST RESPONSE is NULL");
```

The strange thing is If I made an html file and posted data manually the code works in the browser but regarding to android, I do not receive any data back or more specifically any data after manipulating the cursor. any echo statements before that line is received in Android.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PHP script works from the browser. Then it's perhaps a data encoding problem.

Try using json_encode($result->getNext()) instead of var_dump($result->getNext()).

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I tried this also. Still same problem